# Cannot connect to WebDAV from Windows Explorer, but able to from IE?

Tags: linux, windows-7, webdav

I am unable to connect to map a `WebDAV` server location in Windows Explorer that I have successfully connected to via Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know what the reason for this would be?

I can get to the point where Windows asks me for my credentials, but when I put the correct username/password combination in, it will not authenticate.
 Why is this happening?